# linking c++ with Fortran and undefined reference

Tags: c++, reference, linker, fortran, undefined

I am trying to pass the array between functions of c++ and fortran. The Fortran code looks like:

```
PROGRAM vector_adder
  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER,allocatable :: a(:),b(:),c(:)
  INTEGER :: i, num
        num = 6
  allocate(a(num),b(num),c(num))
  !C fill vectors with values
  DO i = 1,num
      a(i) = i*i
      b(i) = i
  END DO

  CALL ADD_VECTORS(a,b,c,num)

  WRITE(*,'(I5,I5,I5)') (c(i),i =1,num)

  STOP
END PROGRAM
```

And the C++ code looks like:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void add_vectors__(int* a, int* b, int* c, int& num);

extern "C" void add_vectors_(int* a, int* b, int* c, int& num)
{
        add_vectors__(a, b, c, num);

}

void add_vectors__(int* a, int* b, int* c, int& num)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i<num; i++)
    {
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
        cout <<c[i]<<endl;
    }

}
```

And I compile the code as:

```
rm -r *.o
rm -r prog
g++ -c c++Code.cpp
gfortran -c fCode.f90
gfortran -o prog fCode.o c++Code.o
./prog
```

If I remove the line of court in the c++ file, the code runs. But introducing the cout line gives me the following errors of undefined references as:

```
c++Code.o: In function `add_vectors__(int*, int*, int*, int&)':
c++Code.cpp:(.text+0xc0): undefined reference to `std::cout'
c++Code.cpp:(.text+0xc5): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(int)'
c++Code.cpp:(.text+0xcf): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
c++Code.cpp:(.text+0xda): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
c++Code.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
c++Code.cpp:(.text+0x110): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
c++Code.cpp:(.text+0x125): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
./run: line 6: ./prog: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

The functions listed are from the C++ runtime library `libstdc++`. Since you're using `gfortran` to build the final library, it will not link in `libstdc++` unless you explicitly tell `gfortran` to do so.

Using `g++` or `gfortran` to link `.o` files is a convenient shorthand. The real linker is `ld`; the other commands just tell `ld` what their respective libraries are.